# How to backup and restore PostgreSQL instance, including role privileges?

Tags: postgresql

I tried a bunch of different tutorials online, but they tend to omit the actual restore commands, or they reset role privileges back to nothing, or they use plain SQL backups in a way that errors (non-idempotent) with any leftover data. I'm not sure what to do for this.

What is some working syntax to 100% backup & restore a PostgreSQL instance?

Answer (score 0):

Most common way - simple, doesn't require file system access, but too slow for huge databases:

Backup: pg_dumpall > backup.sql

Restore: psql -f backup.sql

For bigger databases you will probably want to use the snapshot approach (e.g. using LVM, ZFS, BTRFS), and then tar up the contents of the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ pg_dumpall --clean -U <user> -f backup.sql
$ psql -U <user> -f backup.sql
```

Caution:

- The user must have administrative privileges on the PostgreSQL instance.
- `pg_dump` ignores privileges, compared to `pg_dumpall`.
- If you forget `--clean`, then the .SQL script will collide with any leftovers currently in the database.